# filter list based on input field in react using search regular expression

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to filter the list based on user input. For that, I have used search regular expression to filter out data and then changing state using this.setState() method but when user type something in the input field then it should retrieve list according to it. it's not working as per expectation.can anyone suggest what's wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

SearchBox.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SourceData from "../assets/continents.json";

class SearchBox extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    sourceData: []
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      sourceData: SourceData
    });
  };

  filterList = e => {
    const updatedList = this.state.sourceData.filter(item => {
      return item.toLowerCase().search(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({ sourceData: updatedList });
  };

  render() {
    const searchBox = (
      <input
        type="text"
        onClick={this.handleChange}
        onChange={this.filterList}
      />
    );
    const selectBox = this.state.sourceData.map(option => (
      <li key={option.continent}>{option.continent}</li>
    ));

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Step 1</h2>
        <h3>Select a continent.</h3>
        {searchBox}
        {selectBox && <ul>{selectBox}</ul>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBox;
```

continents.json

```
[
  {
    "continent": "Africa",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Nigeria",
        "flag": "ð³ð¬"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ethiopia",
        "flag": "ðªð¹"
      },
      {
        "name": "Egypt",
        "flag": "ðªð¬"
      },
      {
        "name": "DR Congo",
        "flag": "ð¨ð©"
      },
      {
        "name": "South Africa",
        "flag": "ð¿ð¦"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "continent": "America",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "USA",
        "flag": "ðºð¸"
      },
      {
        "name": "Brazil",
        "flag": "ð§ð·"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mexico",
        "flag": "ð²ð½"
      },
      {
        "name": "Colombia",
        "flag": "ð¨ð´"
      },
      {
        "name": "Argentina",
        "flag": "ð¦ð·"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "continent": "Asia",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "China",
        "flag": "ð¨ð³"
      },
      {
        "name": "India",
        "flag": "ð®ð³"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indonesia",
        "flag": "ð®ð©"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pakistan",
        "flag": "ðµð°"
      },
      {
        "name": "Bangladesh",
        "flag": "ð§ð©"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "continent": "Europe",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Russia",
        "flag": "ð·ðº"
      },
      {
        "name": "Germany",
        "flag": "ð©ðª"
      },
      {
        "name": "UK",
        "flag": "ð¬ð§"
      },
      {
        "name": "France",
        "flag": "ð«ð·"
      },
      {
        "name": "Italy",
        "flag": "ð®ð¹"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "continent": "Oceania",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Australia",
        "flag": "ð¦ðº"
      },
      {
        "name": "Papua New Guinea",
        "flag": "ðµð¬"
      },
      {
        "name": "New Zealand",
        "flag": "ð³ð¿"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fiji",
        "flag": "ð«ð¯"
      },
      {
        "name": "Solomon Islands",
        "flag": "ð¸ð§"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

in below output it's not filtering list.

output ::

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. How you need the output and currently what output you are getting?

Comment: when user type something in input text field it should filter the result and retrieve the data

Comment: What output you are getting right now?

Comment: nothing it's not filtering list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working code. Let me know if you face any issue:

[image: Edit React-simple-calculator]

This function has the issue in your code:

```
filterList = e => {
    const updatedList = this.state.sourceData.filter(item => {
      return (
        item.continent.toLowerCase().search(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      );
    });
    this.setState({ filterData: updatedList });
  };
```

Basically you have to use `item.continent.toLowerCase()` instead of `item.toLowerCase()`

Comment: List should only be displayed when user click on input box.. that's why in handlechange method I change the state

Comment: @Riya Updated. Please check.

Comment: I am still not getting this logic

Comment: SourceData is a json file name. so I can't write name of continent in array[]

Comment: What part of the code you are not getting? Please be precise so i can help.

Comment: If you share your SourceData json file, i will align my answer to that. Since i dont have one, so i have used simple array to demonstrate the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188378/discussion-between-riya-and-arpit-agrawal).

Comment: Let me share my json file here

Comment: I added json file above.

Comment: Hi @Riya. Updated. Please check.

Comment: SourceData file contains whole json Data and in array we just want continent then how can we write entire file name sourceData ?

Comment: @Riya please check your chat. I have answered over there. Let's discuss this in chat only. Comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: I have one more question to your code..posted on discussion

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SourceData from "../assets/continents.json";

class SearchBox extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    sourceData: SourceData,
    filterData: SourceData
  };

  filterList = e => {
    const updatedList = this.state.sourceData.filter(item => {
      return item.toLowerCase().search(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({ filterData: updatedList });
  };

  render() {
    const searchBox = (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={this.filterList}
      />
    );
    const selectBox = this.state.filterData.map(option => (
      <li key={option.continent}>{option.continent}</li>
    ));

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Step 1</h2>
        <h3>Select a continent.</h3>
        {searchBox}
        {selectBox && <ul>{selectBox}</ul>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBox;
```

You can seperate your maindata and filter data and always filter list from main data

Comment: Can you console log updatedList  and check are you getting filter list over there?

Comment: if you are getting output can you post runnable program here?

Comment: Somebody has already given you sandbox link. Now you won't need my code :)